# How to include before/after hooks in test report with AVA?

Tags: javascript, ava

I have the following `test.js` file:

```
const test = require("ava");
test.before("foo", t => {
    someSetupThatMightThrow();
});
test("bar", t => {
    t.pass();
});
test.after("baz", t => {
    someTeardownThatMightThrow();
});
```

After running `ava --verbose`, if any of the hooks throw, I get a red X in the test report, which is great. But if nothing throws, I get only one green checkmark for the `bar` test:

[image: green-checkmark bar 1 test passed]

I would like to see green checkmarks relative to the before/after hooks as well, instead of them simply being omitted. How can I do this?

Comment: You shouldn't be running tests in before and after hooks at all; they're for setup and teardown of dependencies

Comment: @Hamms I know... In my attempt to create a minimal example, I ended up giving the wrong idea. I've edited my question, please take a look again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We won't output those in our regular reporters, sorry. I'd say don't worry: the hooks will run.

(Eventually down the line maybe we'd have a much more low-level reporter which would include this information, that you could build your own reporter on, but that's a ways away.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for this great library :)